# Have not got the "Get Items" choice in Sharepoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-online

Many thanks for the info, I have gone in to the workflow but I can only see "Get Items from a Dictionary" when typing in the workflow and cannot see it under actions? Would you know why?

Kind Regards Daniel

Answer (score 0):

The Dictionary variable type is a new variable type in the SharePoint Workflow platform that you can use with SharePoint Designer 2013. So first make sure you are handling 2013 platform workflow.

And The following are the three actions specifically designed for the Dictionary variable type.

- Build Dictionary
- Count Items in a Dictionary
- Get an Item from a Dictionary

We do not have an action called `Get Items from a Dictionary` by default.

Reference:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/understanding-dictionary-actions-in-sharepoint-designer

Answer (score 0):

I think as an alternate you can use the "**Call HTTP Web Service**" Action to get the list items from SharePoint which is more straight forward than the **Get Items from a Dictionary** action.

**Example**:

[image: Call HTTP Web Service Action in SharePoint Designer Workflow]